# Typescript : push multiple objects to same key dynamically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongodb-query

I am working on new project using **expressjs** + **MongoDB** + **typescript**.

Collection after executing mongo query :

```
[{
    "_id": 1,
    "mixerId": 1,
    "mixerName": "Tejuino",
    "mixerType": "1",
    "price": 0,
    "isActive": 1
},
{
    "_id": 2,
    "mixerId": 1,
    "mixerName": "Izze",
    "price": 0,
    "mixerType": "1",
    "isActive": 1
},

{
    "_id": 1,
    "mixerId": 2,
    "mixerName": "REGULAR SODA",
    "mixerType": "2",
    "price": 0,
    "isActive": 1
},
{
    "_id": 2,
    "mixerId": 2,
    "mixerName": "Fanta Grape",
    "mixerType": "2",
    "price": 0,
    "isActive": 1
}, {
    "_id": 1,
    "mixerId": 3,
    "mixerName": "GIN & BITTER LEMON",
    "mixerType": "3",
    "price": 0,
    "isActive": 1
}]
```

I want to convert this structure into below format using typescript:

```
  {
    "juices" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "mixerId" : 1,
            "mixerName" : "Tejuino",
            "price" : 0,
            "isActive" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "mixerId" : 1,
            "mixerName" : "Izze",
            "price" : 0,
            "isActive" : 1
        }
    ],
    "soda" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "mixerId" : 2,
            "mixerName" : "REGULAR SODA",
            "price" : 0,
            "isActive" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "mixerId" : 2,
            "mixerName" : "Fanta Grape",
            "price" : 0,
            "isActive" : 1
        }
    ],
    "others" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "mixerId" : 3,
            "mixerName" : "GIN & BITTER LEMON",
            "price" : 0,
            "isActive" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Please Help me.

Comment: You can do that in your aggregation query as well, What defines a doc/product in your collection goes to a category ?

Comment: how..actually am new in mongodb.can u pls help me

Comment: So what defines a product belongs to a category ?

Comment: Its mixerType. Group based on mixerType.

Comment: Can you confirm you only have two types `juices` or `soda` & rest go to others ?

Comment: yes.. 3 types Juice(mixerType:1) ,Soda(mixerType:2),Others(mixerType:3).For Example : i want to group Tejuino,Izze under mixerType 1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** group on mixerType & push docs to v field */
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$mixerType",
            v: {
                $push: "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    },
    /** Using switch rename _id values to actual names & push to k field */
    {
        $project: {
            k: {
                $switch: {
                    branches: [
                        { case: { $eq: ["1", "$_id"] }, then: "juices" },
                        { case: { $eq: ["2", "$_id"] }, then: "soda" }
                    ],
                    default: "others"
                }
            },
            _id: 0,
            v: 1
        }
    },
    /** As we've docs in form of {K:..., v:...} use arrayToObject to convert those to an object type &
     *  to data field */
    {
        $project: {
            data: {
                $arrayToObject: [
                    [
                        "$$ROOT"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    /** Make data field as new root for each doc */
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$data"
        }
    }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p9ckp-o5tbM)

Comment: @deepu : Shouldn't be, how many docs are you dealing with at this stage ? You always use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/index.html to check your queries performance..

Comment: actually there will be a screen for users to add juice,sode,others.

Comment: @deepu : I didn't get that !! Test this query on your DB & let me know how it runs, I'm trying to check this query on your data set, So asking for how many docs are you dealing with !!

Comment: actually there will be more docs.can't predict that excastly because user will add data from app side(mobile).